# Visual Studio Code returns a php xdebug error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have following installation

- Windows 10
- Lavarel with PHP  C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64
- php in Windows path C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64
- Latest version of Visual Code with PHP IntelliSense and PHP Debug

In Windows terminal php -v returns this

```
PHP 7.2.19 (cli) (built: May 29 2019 13:58:59) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

Problem description :
I open Visual Studio Code and a php file with a simple test code like this

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

When I click the OUTPUT panel in Visual Studio I receive this

```
DEBUG     Checking PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG
DEBUG     The xdebug extension is loaded (2.9.1)

DEBUG     Process restarting (PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG=internal|2.9.1|0|*|*)
DEBUG     Running C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\php.exe -n -c C:\Users\graziano\AppData\Local\Temp\1ABE.tmp c:\Users\graziano\.vscode\extensions\felixfbecker.php-intellisense-2.3.14\vendor\felixfbecker\language-server\bin\php-language-server.php --tcp=127.0.0.1:49716 --memory-limit=4095M

DEBUG     Checking PHPLS_ALLOW_XDEBUG
DEBUG     Restarted (65 ms). The xdebug extension is not loaded
```

Why is it returning "The xdebug extension is not loaded" ?
The OUTPUT page should not return the script echo "test" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your zend_extension ist commented out in the cached php.ini

;zend_extension = xxx.dll
C:\Users\graziano\AppData\Local\Temp\1ABE.tmp